# Storing data in Zend_Registry vs Zend_Cache

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache, zend-log, zend-config

So far i have been using `Bootstrap.php` to load my application.ini config into Zend_Registry as well as an instance of logger. I was wondering if storing these inside Zend_Cache would be a better solution as these remain unchanged over lifespan of application and whenever i redeploy application, cache is cleared on first run anyways. Whats your verdict on this?

Someone also suggested to create a controller which has logger and config stored in protected variables and then all of application controllers would inherit from that. I don't find that as a better solution then the current Zend_Registry one, not sure if i am justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page should be useful for you:

[Caching of Zend Framework application configuration file](http://devzone.zend.com/article/14893)

Comment: great resources. How about just putting the (config, navigations, etc static) files in cache using an _init method in bootstrap? The only different is that in this know i know exactly whats being cached as i am doing it manually. Performance would be better or worse in this case when compared with the resource provided? I am just cautious not to add any extra overhead to coding :D

Comment: How are you preventing the cache file from being read in by `Zend_Application` at the moment?  The above is neat because it effectively just wraps how ZF works by default to allow caching.

Comment: good question. Understood the concept and marked as correct answer. Thanks.